# Cisco ASA 5505 cannot ping from inside to outside

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, cisco-asa

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for all the help. I'm having some issue getting my cisco firewall (asa 5505) to ping between zones. The inside zone won't ping with the outside zone and vice versa. But I can get the inside zone to ping with the DMZ and the Outside zone can ping with the DMZ. For whatever reason though I cannot get the inside and outside to accept pings from each other. This has all been done using the CLI/console and would be appreciated if the answers didn't involve use of the ASDM (I can't use ASDM for reasons). 
I have tried tons of google searches but none of the solutions worked for me or involved use of the ASDM.

I think it's NAT (Not exactly my strong suit by far, never has been). However I have included the majority of my start/running config. Some info has been omitted (i.e. hostname and passwords).

```
!
ASA Version 7.2(4)
interface Ethernet0/0
 description inside network
nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.27.6.2 255.255.255.252 
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 description DMZ network
 nameif DMZ
 security-level 50
 ip address 10.65.4.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 description outside network
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 209.65.5.2 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!

ftp mode passive
access-list outside extended permit tcp any any eq smtp 
access-list outside extended permit udp any any eq domain 
access-list outside extended permit tcp any any eq www 
access-list outside extended permit icmp any any 
access-list DMZ extended permit tcp any any eq smtp 
access-list DMZ extended permit tcp any any eq 50636 
access-list DMZ extended permit tcp any any eq domain 
access-list DMZ extended permit tcp any any eq www 
access-list DMZ extended permit udp any any eq domain 
access-list DMZ extended permit icmp any any 
pager lines 24
mtu inside 1500
mtu DMZ 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (DMZ) 1 10.65.4.10-10.65.4.30
global (DMZ) 1 10.65.4.31
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 10.25.0.0 255.255.0.0
static (inside,DMZ) 10.25.0.0 10.25.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 
static (outside,DMZ) 10.65.4.2 209.65.5.3 netmask 255.255.255.255 
static (outside,DMZ) 10.65.4.3 209.65.5.4 netmask 255.255.255.255 
access-group DMZ in interface DMZ
access-group outside in interface outside
route inside 10.25.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.27.6.1 1
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 209.65.5.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat   0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
!
class-map icmp-class
 match default-inspection-traffic
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect netbios 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect skinny 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect sip 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect icmp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
Cryptochecksum:bfa954ee3900016b01cca15cfcf36eec
: end
```

In the above the block of text the lines regarding static NAT for outside and DMZ like `static (outside,DMZ) 10.65.4.X 209.65.5.X` originally was `static (DMZ,outside) 209.65.5.X 10.65.4.X` however I read that it was bad practice to map a higher sec level to a lower sec, so I changed it. I have also tried switching the ACL's to allow everything thru for testing, using `ip any any` in place of what I actually want to get through, still with no results. Thanks for reviewing this gigantic wall of text and offering any advice, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the ASDM at all?

Comment: No the ASDM version is rather old and doesn't work with win7, we don't have anything older than win7.

Comment: Are you pinging to and from the ASA, or are you using a device on each side? What specific error messages do you get when the pings fail?

Comment: i'm using devices on each side, the error I get is "request timed out". Once again thanks for the help.